# Deregister dequeue JS scripts except on 1 product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, javascript

I need to deregister JS scripts everywhere except on one product page, so far this is my code:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );
if ( !is_product('67688') ) {
wp_deregister_script( 'wc-lottery-jquery-plugin' );
wp_deregister_script( 'wc-lottery-countdown' );
wp_deregister_script( 'wc-lottery-countdown-language' );
wp_deregister_script( 'wc-lottery-public' );
}
}
```

Is this correct? Many thanks for your confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use 'wp_enqueue_scripts' hook and try with condition like this-

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript' );
function my_deregister_javascript(){
    if( get_the_ID() != '67688' ) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'wc-lottery-jquery-plugin' );
    }
}
```

for front-end

Answer (score 0):

The above would not work, this method hasn't yet been tested but seems correct:

```
    global $product;
    if ( is_object($product)  && ($product->get_type() === 'lottery')  ) {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-lottery-jquery-plugin' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-lottery-countdown' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-lottery-countdown-language' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-lottery-public' );

    }
```